# Twitter and iOS 5

Tags: xcode, twitter, ios5

I need to integrate Twitter for iOS 5 but I musn't use Twitter Framework of Xcode 4. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) directly.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter framework in iOS 5 is only available when you include the framework. Of course.

If you want to retain compatibility with iOS 4 (why'd you do that anyway?), you should use weak linking against the framework. This allows the app to run on iOS 4 as well.

If you don't want to use the framework altogether, you definitely miss out on all the new features such as automatic account importing. In that case you'd talk to the API itself (see http://dev.twitter.com for more info) or use a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gemmell's `MGTwitterEngine` may do what you need.

The source code can be downloaded from https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine